Why is the padded copper line going into HVAC hissing and blowing cold air?
In the attic the HVAC sounds like it's leaking air or something from the big padded copper line going in the pipe is cold and right where it connects or go into the unit is blowing back cold air my unit is not blowing as cold but I can't see inside

Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour].

You are probably hearing the fan blowing air out of the air handler because the opening for the line is not sealed well. This can be sealed better, to eliminate the hiss but will not result in colder air.
Hissing from freon gas escaping would only last for a short time before the unit was out of freon.
You noticed the hissing because you took interest in examining the unit when it failed to produce enough cold air. ( It has probably been going on for a long time.)  It's time for an inspection by an HVAC pro. An overly hot liquid line ( small one) is a sign of low freon and possible air in the system.
First check the usual things, like the return filter needing replacement, the service ducts being clear. Outside check that the coils on the compressor unit are clean and free of debris.
